# Kio estas la Esperanta vorto de ‘Athlete's foot’?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Kiel mi tradukus la anglan vorton ‘Athlete's foot’ en Esperanton?

Mi pensas pri io kiel piedfunguso aŭ piedŝimo, sed la unua Gugle donas neniujn rezultojn kaj la lasta nur unu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[La vortaro de John Wells](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) sugestas *pieda tinio*.